# Convert list with tags into text list, python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tags, append

I have a list of tags I have obtained from beatifulSoup, I am trying to remove the tags:

```
res= [<a href="/cities/Bilbao/place/p/95854/Guggenheim+Museum+Bilbao">Guggenheim Museum Bilbao</a>,
 <a href="/cities/Bilbao/place/p/380902/Vizcaya+Bridge">Vizcaya Bridge</a>,
 <a href="/cities/Bilbao/place/p/95864/Mercado+de+la+Ribera">Mercado de la Ribera</a>,
 <a href="/cities/Bilbao/place/p/95863/Azkuna+Zentroa">Azkuna Zentroa</a>,
 <a href="/cities/Bilbao/place/p/95846/Plaza+Berria">Plaza Berria</a>]
```

I can do manually do it one by one by: `sites = res[0].text`, but I would like to automate it, I had thought about creating a `for` loop, but I am so new to python and programming that I can not construct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop as suggested.

Another viable option is to use `map`

```
res = list(map(lambda x: x.text, res))
```

I suggest you stay away from BeautifulSoup or other libraries until you have a fair grasp of the python standard library.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

```
for r in res:
    site = r.text
```